# Converting Authorization Codes To Access Tokens in laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle, laravel-passport

I am using laravel passport to creat oauth .

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::get('/redirect', function () {
    $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => '3',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/callback',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => '',
    ]);

    return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
});
Route::get('/auth/callback', function (Request $request) {
    $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
    $response = $http->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => '3',
            'client_secret' => 'client_secret',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/callback',
            'code' => $request->code,
        ],
    ]);

    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
});
```

Here Redirecting For Authorization is successful and while Converting Authorization Codes To Access Tokens using Guzzle the page keeps loading with out returning any response here.
Even using CURL inside is returning false. But while trying from post man or CURL from diffrent destination it returns valid data. Is it framwork/package bug?

Comment: try `dd($response->getBody())` and see what you get

Comment: nothing. it keeps loading and loading....

Comment: It is probably going into some kind of infinite loop. Check the logs

Answer (score 2):

do not use GuzzleHttp

use this code:

```
$request->request->add([
      'username' => $request->email,
      'password' => $request->password,
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => '2',
        'client_secret' => 'GT6IA4aasdasdBhgrPvxHkGeXBasdasdST5F',
        'scope' => ''
    ]);

    $tokenRequest = Request::create(
        url('oauth/token'),
        'post'
    );
    $response = Route::dispatch($tokenRequest);
```

and do not forget to add this on the top

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Comment: I am using hyn multi-tenancy and this solved my problem. GuzzleHttp wasn't respecting the 'tenancy.enforce' middleware in AuthServiceProvider > boot() > Passport::routes(null, ['middleware' => 'tenancy.enforce']);

Answer (score 1):

Probably you run your code on PHP's integrated web server. If yes, then it won't work, because it's able to handle only one request concurrently. So, if you do an HTTP request from a local script to another local script... Then you have a deadlock.

Try to run PHP-FPM locally instead.